# Cannot execute bash script in Snakemake

Tags: bash, snakemake

This is my first question on Snakemake as the existing resources and forums helped me immensely to solve most of my problems.

The problem I currently had is that I cannot make the bash script execute in Snakemake, though I was able to execute the same bash script just fine on the command line

Here is how I run the bash script on the command line successfully

```
bash scripts/genome_coverage.sh -m results/mapped_reads -o final_out.txt
```

But when I run it in Snakemake, I get the error.

Here is the rule in the Snakefile that corresponds to the executing bash script

```
rule genome_coverage:
    input:
        "results/mapped_reads"
    output:
        "genome_coverage.txt"
    script:
        "scripts/genome_coverage.sh -m {input} -o {output}"
```

And this is the error I am getting. I don't know what I am doing wrong here

```
Error in rule genome_coverage:
    jobid: 16
    output: genome_coverage.txt
RuleException:
NameError in line 153 of /Illumina-mRNA/Snakefile:
The name 'input' is unknown in this context. Please make sure that you defined that variable. Also note that braces not used for variable access have to be escaped by repeating them, i.e. {{print $1}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace `script` with `shell`:

```
rule genome_coverage:
    input:
        "results/mapped_reads"
    output:
        "genome_coverage.txt"
    shell:
        "scripts/genome_coverage.sh -m {input} -o {output}"
```

Comment: Just to expand a little.  Script is for external python, R or julia script files.  If you just need bash commands you can use shell.  If you want inline python you can use run, which also opens up using the shell function provided by snakemake.